# How do I get the Mesh from a 3D model?

Tags: java, mesh, jmonkeyengine, 3d-model

Im working with the jMonkeySDK on a 3D java game at the moment.
I really need to know how I can get the mesh from my spatial (3D model).
Does anyone have experience with this engine and knows how I can have access to the mesh?

I searched in the documentation and read a lot of tutorials. But I dont find a way.
Hope someone can help me

Comment: Hmm, is the spatial castable to Geometry (some spatials are), if so it's easy from that point

Comment: Ehm, I dont know... I found this http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/forum/topic/cast-spatial-to-geometry/
But I dont know really what the actual fix there was...?

Comment: within your code, where you've got your spatial as `spatial` type `System.out.println("Is castable:" + spatial instanceof Geometry);` and that will give you your answer

Comment: The reason it might not be castable is because a spacial can be either a geometry (woo!) or a node (boo!) that may have several geometrys connected to it (woo?)

Answer (score 0):

Models inside jME3 are stored as `Spatials`, with `Spatials` mostly being either a `Node` or a `Geometry`.

`Nodes` just contain other `Spatials` (but can transform their position, rotation, etc) while `Geometries` just contain `Mesh`es and the `Material`s and other information associated with the `Mesh`.

The easiest way to do this is to open the model in the SDK and use the Scene Explorer window to view the layout of `Nodes` and `Meshes`. You can then determine what you need to do, as often you need to drill down through a few `Nodes`, find the `Geometry` you are interested in, and then get the `Mesh` from that `Geometry`.

Alternatively programmatically you can just recurse down through the `Node` structure, iterating over each child. If the child is a `Node` then scan that too, if it is a Geometry then get the `Mesh`.